# How does Twilio's "Programmable Video" work?

Tags: ios, video, twilio, twilio-api

I'm building a streaming iOS app in Swift. Looking at the docs `https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video` I understand that you can create live video chat rooms on the fly.

My use case is a bit different:

User A access a room, hit 'record' and start streaming a video of himself to Twilio storage. Creates a thumbnail in the UI. User B enters the same room and click the video thumbnail - that video should be streamed down to User B.

If user A is talking (Streaming up) and user B is in the room at the same time, it should be possible to 'Go live', which would start a live video chat room that other users can join too.

Main question: Does Twilio Programmable Video allow streaming up and down using their storage?

Secondary question: Would you say Twilio Programmable Video is the right choice for this use case or would you recommend another service?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'll answer this the other way around that you asked if that's ok.

If User A is currently streaming to a room and recording it (having [created the room in `group` mode with `RecordParticipantsOnConnect` set to true](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#post-list-resource)) and another user wants to join the room, then they can. They just need an [access token that gives them access to the room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/user-identity-access-tokens#limit-room-access). They will then be able to join the room and chat and be recorded too.

Once a recording is complete, you will receive a [webhook to the `statusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/status-callbacks) that was set for the room. The callback for the recording will have the `recording-complete` and will include a `MediaURL` for the recording as well as the `Uri` and `Sid` for the [recording resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/recordings-resource).

You can use the media URL or the recording resource to get the binary data, which for videos will be in `.mkv` format. If you want to stream this video to your users, you may want to download the video and convert to a playable format. Or upload it to a streaming service.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: A question, this recording accessible only when the talks ended? Or I can access these data on the fly?

Comment: The recording isn't available until the room is closed. However you have access to the video in each client and could join with a ghost client if you wanted to process it on the fly for any reason.